# where do I ask questions about woocomerce code implementation and customization

Tags: discussion

I have some woocommerce related questions and I would like to send it to the comunity, it happens very often, can someone tell me the right place to make this questions

Comment: questions about the stack itself go on the meta stack, I've migrated your question here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of places but not here, this isn't a WooCommerce community, and you can't ask for help with the APIs of 3rd party plugins/themes here.

As for where you can get help with WooCommerce, there is a [support route](https://woocommerce.com/my-account/create-a-ticket/) if you log into woocommerce.com, an [official WooCommerce community slack](https://woocommerce.com/community-slack/), [facebook groups](https://www.facebook.com/search/groups/?q=woocommerce), [local meetups](https://woocommerce.com/meetups/), an [official job board](https://woocommerce.com/search/?collections=service). I know some of the FB WordPress groups allow WooCommerce questions but check beforehand.

To a lesser extent, StackOverflow itself is an option as it's a general programming stack with a much wider scope, though that's no guarantee of a quality response. In the past attempts were made to start a WooCommerce stack, but it didn't garner the support needed to graduate to a beta on Area 51. People were happy to ask questions but almost nobody was answering them.